# Hiding Routes in React Header based on Express.js User login status

Tags: reactjs, express, passport.js

I have an application that uses *express.js* as the server side language and *React* on the front-end. I use *passport.js* to authenticate routes in the server, using local login and facebook strategies (no JWT). I use *express-session* to manage the session, which seems straight forward ( or insufficient, which I do not know yet, for my case, as its work in progress ).

My requirement is to hide/show few links in the Header component. 
i.e.,

- Log In
- Sign Up

should show up in index page, when user has not logged in, but hidden when he is logged in. Likewise, few links should be hidden when the user is not yet logged in.

What is the best wat to check this from the client? Making an AJAX call is not ideal, as I may have more use cases of checking if the user session is valid from the client.

I can see the default *connect.sid* cookie, which the express creates, but how do I make use of it, or is there a best way for the client to know that the user is already logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options. Here are some:

1. You can check for the presence of a different cookie in the browser, and use that as your metric for whether or not you are "logged in". Your browser won't know if the session has expired server side, so you still have to account for the fact that you may be logged out and not know it. Additionally, you have to be sure to clear this cookie when logging out and set it when logging in.
2. When starting, your browser can make a AJAX request to get the currently logged in user. This might be useful for all sorts of things, such as displaying the user's name when logged in. You really only need to do this once (on page load and on login), then keep track of the user's login state stored in memory. You mentioned you don't want to do this, but it is fairly common.
3. When loading the page, you can inject the user into the page. For example, when the page loads there will be a `<script>` tag containing `window.currentUser = null` or an object representing the user. You can use this to "bootstrap" the login state without needing an AJAX request.

To clarify, you can't use the `connect.sid` cookie by itself because this cookie is just the ID of the session, not the session data itself. Only the server knows the session data that's being stored for that user, not the client. You need some way aside from this cookie for the server to tell the client that it's logged in, and the client to keep track of that state.

If you want the client to know from the ID component itself, you'll want to look at token options like JWTs.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I am gonna try the solution based on your suggestions, starting with a cookie, other than _connect.sid_ and accessing it from the client. If not, will try out the AJAX method, and finally JWTs, which I am not quite confident right now, but eventually, and for which, I need to change some of my auth solutions too. Will update how it goes.

Comment: Great, I hope it goes well!